# Using realtive path to create/ access sqlite3 database

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to create a sqlite3 DB from python in IntelliJ running on mac os. Below screenshot shows the file structure

[image]

Highlighted folder `testing_sqlite` is current program in which I have written my code, I was able to create `mydb` file using full path, but how to do so using relative path

Error is

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I tried copying relative path of database folder by right-clicking but below code did not work as well

```
db = sqlite3.connect('vkey/architectures/Energy_efficient/database/mydb1')
```

however, below code works but I want it to be in the folder as I will be creating more databases

```
db = sqlite3.connect('mydb1')
```

Comment: Does the directory `database` exist where `os.getcwd()` says you're running?

Comment: yes, it does exist on the file system, if this is what you are asking!

Comment: What I mean is... if you do `os.path.abspath('database/mydb1')` do you get the same result as your connection path that works...?

Comment: Note that `vkey/architectures/Energy_efficient/database/mydb1` is a relative path and not an absolute path... so.. not sure what you're asking now...

Comment: os.getcwd() =/Users/amar/Downloads/vKey_XenServer 2/vkey/architectures/Energy_efficient/deamons
 
os.path.abspath('database/mydb1')= /Users/amar/Downloads/vKey_XenServer 2/vkey/architectures/Energy_efficient/deamons/database/mydb1

Comment: And is there a directory called `database` in `/Users/amar/Downloads/vKey_XenServer 2/vkey/architectures/Energy_efficient/deamons ` ? It looks like the one that works will be looking at: `/Users/amar/Downloads/vKey_XenServer 2/vkey/architectures/Energy_efficient/deamons/vkey/architectures/Energy_efficient/database/mydb1`... (eg - not the daemon directory but the architectures directory)

Comment: no there is no directory there by name of `database`, I am astonished why the `cwd` is  `demons` while I am running the file in `Energy_efficient`. Actually, I moved this file from `demons` to `Energy_efficient`, but why still the 'cwd' is inside `demons`

Comment: All depends how you're running it or your IDE settings... *shrugs*...